# Continuous varying color in three adjacent rectangles

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, gradient

I can draw three adjacent rectangle with three different color like below:

[image]

Here, In these three rectengle I can use varying color like below:

[image]

1. Upper rectangle is varying color from **BLUE** to **GREEN**
2. Middle rectangle is uniform color of **GREEN**
3. Lower rectangle is varying color from **GREEN** to **RED**

But, I need something different. I want to use a continuous varying color from **BLUE** to **RED** in these three rectangle.. I can use one rectangle instead of three. But I have to use three rectangles.. I want like below:

[image]

Is it possible to do these?

[NOTE: There can be varible number of rectangles. Its a sample of three rectangles. I can also get 100 rectangles. And then I will vary color from **BLUE** to **RED** from up to down]

Actually, I have drawn a car using lots of rectangles. And now I need to color it with gradient color.

[image]

Comment: I am confused on what you need: "I can use one rectangle instead of three. But I have to use three rectangles." Pleas explain what is it you need.

Comment: Actually I draw something using a lots of rectangle.. Now I need to color them

Comment: So you want to draw N rectangles altogether having a gradient from blue to red as if it was drawn by a single rectangle?

Comment: @MaticOblak, Yes.. You are right. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, nothing easier..

Comment: @MaticOblak, To make carve I have used lots of rectangles..

Comment: If what you want is to draw a car shaped gradient then you best look into stencil buffer or use the alpha channel to redraw the custom shape with the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpolation you see by using varying color in the fragment shader is a linear interpolation of color components as such:

```
R = R1 + (R2-R1)*scale
G = G1 + (G2-G1)*scale
B = B1 + (B2-B1)*scale
A = A1 + (A2-A1)*scale
```

In your case `C1(0,0,1,1)` and `C2(1,0,0,1)` is interpolated. The scale is the a relative value from first to last vertex in range of [0,1].

What you need to do is implement the same algorithm when setting the vertex colors in order to achieve a smooth gradient. To use the algorithm I posted you already have the 2 colors, all you need is the scale: The top vertexes scale is always 0 and the bottom are always 1. All in between must then be relatively computed: For 2 equal rectangles you need to get the scale for the middle position which is .5; If there were 3 equal triangles you need 2 middle scales such as .3333 and .6666... So the pattern is that for N rectangles you need N+1 scales:

```
scale[i] = 1.0/N * i
```

If the rectangles are not of equal size what you need to do is find the sum of rectangle heights and then distribute the values between then.